# redirect traffic to aws S3 / Cloudfront but keep dns and email at namesecure

Tags: dns, amazon-web-services, cloud, nameserver

I have a domain registered at Namesecure but want to host the content on AWS S3 (also using Cloudfront).  I want to keep DNS and email handling at Namesecure. How should I go about this?  Thank you!

*edit, added this:*

I have read the material referenced below, thank you!  I have created a hosted zone in Route 53 and a Cloudfront distribution.  But I'm still not sure how to connect that with the DNS on Namesecure.

I don't want to change the DNS to AWS, because I want to maintain the email setup on Namesecure.

I was thinking of editing A records in the Zone File on Namesecure, but that would require an IP address on AWS to point the A records at, and I don't see that I have an IP address.

Currently, the A records in Namesecure look like this:

```
A Records:
  www.mydomain.com. IN A 205.178.189.131
  mydomain.com. IN A 205.178.189.131
  *.mydomain.com. IN A 205.178.189.131
```

When I created the Route 53 hosted zone, it automatically created an NS record with four Amazon DNS servers:

```
ns-78.awsdns-09.com
ns-649.awsdns-17.net
ns-1649.awsdns-14.co.uk
ns-1477.awsdns-56
```

Current nameservers at Namesecure are:

```
DNS1.NAMESECURE.COM207.204.40.155
DNS2.NAMESECURE.COM207.204.21.155
```

It seems to me I need to tell Namesecure to use the AWS name servers for web access but not for email.

Maybe I need to use the URL forwarding feature at Namesecure?  But if I forward it to the S3 URL (e.g. `http://mydomain.com.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com`) I'm bypassing Cloudfront.  Perhaps I forward to the Cloudfront domain name (e.g. `kjhklsdhfksdfhkjsdh.cloudfront.net`) with "URL gripper" on so that the user will still see `mydomain.com` in the address bar?

But, experimenting with that, it seems to be working for the main site, `mydomain.com` but not for instance for `mydomain.com/myfolder/index.html`

Also, no matter what folder (page) I go to (by clicking on menu choices on the main page), the URL remains `mydomain.com`, which is not ideal -- I'd rather have it reflect the folder I'm in.

Comment: Have you done any research? Have you looked for any documentation guides on Namesecure (how to configure domain DNS) and AWS (how to configure DNS manually)? Have you contacted either company?

Answer (score 0):

1. Find Amazon's documentation for how to setup your-own-domain-DNS to point to their infrastructure (AWS, Cloundfront, etc.). [Here is some of their documentation on that](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-aws-resources.html)
2. Login to Namesecure, setup DNS there to point 80/HTTP & 443/HTTPS & anything else to AWS. [Their Product Setup page details](https://www.namesecure.com/productSetUp.page#):

   > What it does:
   >   Using NameSecure's DNS will mean that all web forwarding, e-mail
   >   forwarding, MX records, CNAMEs and A Records will be handled by
   >   NameSecure. (You can change your nameservers at any time.)
   >
   > How to use it
   >
   > 1. Log in to My Account and click Modify/Update for the domain name.
   > 2. Click the WHOIS Info tab.
   > 3. Click Modify Domain Name Servers.
   > 4. Click Ok.